# Insert form-component dynamically

Tags: angular, angular2-router3

[image: dynamicform]

I want to insert dynamically a form module/component containing the html and formgroup definition. The header/footer/buttons (white) are always the same. Is it possible to start the form-parent (white).

```
<parent-form dynform="dynamicform"></parent-form>
```

The parent/dynamic should be able to communicate with each other, the parent is in control.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctlythe point, what you are looking for is exactly what the Angular2 Router is providing.
Check for Routing in the official documentation (e.g. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html or https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html).

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

> The header/footer/buttons (white) are always the same

You could use `router-outlet`

1. You define each area (Header, Body, and Footer) as `router-outlet`, you could specify your root template like below. Notice that, we specifically set the `name` attribute to `header` and `footer`, and leave the main area as it is.

   ```
   <router-outlet name='header'></router-outlet>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   <router-outlet name='footer'></router-outlet>
   ```
2. You specify what component will be rendered on what `router-outlet` on your router configuration. Notice, that `HeaderComponent` has `header` as the `outlet`. As you can guess, `outlet` should match the `router-outlet` name attribute

   ```
   { 
     path: 'pageA', 
     children : [
        {path:'', component: MainBodyComponent},
        {path:'', component: HeaderComponent, outlet:'header'},
        {path:'', component: FooterComponent, outlet:'footer'}
     ] 
   }
   ```

See this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Su2fNPKOnQkZpnUb99Vh?p=preview) for more insight.

Comment: Thnx for your answer. I already have this setup but to communicate you need an extra service. I was hoping for a better solution, without an outlet.
The child is dump with only the input components. The Parent should have the save buttons and valid control.